# How to add company logo during payment

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi everyone I have to create a payment using paypal rest api, but the reference does not help me... It looks like different from the api... 
So.. I have different problems:

1. I would like to put the company logo on the top of paypal page... but i don't know how to do (no invoice, but payment);

[image]

Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal recently launched the facility to put the logo on the checkout page via the use of REST API . You can refer the below url to get more info :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest-experience-overview/

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to another input field with id="cpp_logo_image" name="cpp_logo_image" 
value="Your log link"

HTML Variables for Displaying PayPal Checkout Pages

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B